# Grids using react bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table, react-grid-layout

I want to display 3 cards. I am getting the following error:

> ./src/views/Notifications.jsx
>     Line 28:8:  'Container' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Row, Col, Alert, Container} from "react-bootstrap";
import Button from "components/CustomButton/CustomButton.jsx";
import Typography from "views/Typography.jsx";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch, Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';


class Notifications extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
  <Row>
    <Col>1 of 2</Col>
    <Col>2 of 2</Col>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Col>1 of 3</Col>
    <Col>2 of 3</Col>
    <Col>3 of 3</Col>
  </Row>
</Container>

    )}
}
```

Comment: where are you using the Notifications class? the above snippet you showed works on its own the code has no error on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'
```

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/#container-props